# Do I need to set up Kerberos to use Replication in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql, sql-server, replication, kerberos

I want to setup replication on three SQL servers and one is not configured for Kerberos. (The SPNs are not setup yet)

Do I need Kerberos and Pass-through delegation working to use replication in SQL Server 2005?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. But you will need the replication agent(s) to run under the context of account with the relevant permissions. See MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151868.aspx).